# How to display images uploaded from django admin to heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I deployed my django project on heroku. The site is all working well except for the fact that some images are broken. These images are all images which I uploaded to my site in local server via the django admin. These images were uploaded to my site on local server by providing the url in image field in django admin page. All the images which are hard coded in the html code and are static/images folder in my project are displayed. Any changes I should make to my settings.py file to dipslay these pictures? How to resolve this?

My settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for ecommerce project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'gm1zyhprh9=9+4@vu*^8g30(pg*xq6e@0z1)h81hc2evd7n*^v'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['market-shaurya.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_filters',
    'store.apps.StoreConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ecommerce.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ecommerce.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]


MEDIA_URL='/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

my store.html templates file

```
{% extends 'store/main.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">

        {% for product in products %}
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="{{product.imageURL}}">
                <div class="middle">
                    <div class="text"><strong><strong>{{product.description}}</strong></strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-element product">
                    <h6><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></h6>
                    <hr>

                    <button data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>

                    <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#">View</a>
                    <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right"><strong>₹{{product.price|floatformat:2}}</strong></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

notice this src="{{product.imageURL}}. This is how I uploaded pictures to this cart.

Comment: How are the images saved on Heroku? If it is saved on Heroku you will have a problem: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: I'll have to use s3 on aws it seems to store my images then.

Answer (score 0):

```
DEBUG = True
```

This solves the problem.

Comment: Not working... Did you find a way to fix that?

Comment: @tiberhockey Its been some time and I don't exactly remember the tech stack as I haven't been working on it for a long time. However, this setting did solve my issue at the time. You can refer to my code for my project here if you want. https://github.com/shaur27/ecommerce-live
I removed aws deployment later. You can also refer to denis ivy youtube tutorials for aws connection if you want. Hope it helps.